# How to get ErrorCode value using jQuery from bellow SPServices xml response

Tags: javascript, jquery, spservices, xml, json

How to get ErrorCode value using jQuery from bellow SPServices xml response:

```
<Results xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
 <Result ID="1,Update">
  <ErrorCode>0x00000000</ErrorCode>
  <z:row ows_ID="4" ows_Title="Title" 
     ows_Modified="2003-06-19 20:31:21" 
     ows_Created="2003-06-18 10:15:58" 
     ows_Author="3;#User1_Display_Name" 
     ows_Editor="7;#User2_Display_Name" ows_owshiddenversion="3" 
     ows_Attachments="-1" 
     ows__ModerationStatus="0" ows_LinkTitleNoMenu="Title" 
     ows_LinkTitle="Title" 
     ows_SelectTitle="4" ows_Order="400.000000000000" 
     ows_GUID="{4962F024-BBA5-4A0B-9EC1-641B731ABFED}" 
     ows_DateColumn="2003-09-04 00:00:00" 
     ows_NumberColumn="791.00000000000000" 
     xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema" />
</Result>
<Result ID="2,Update">
  <ErrorCode>0x00000000</ErrorCode>
  <z:row ows_ID="6" ows_Title="Title" 
     ows_Modified="2003-06-19 20:31:22" 
     ows_Created="2003-06-18 19:07:14" 
     ows_Author="2;#User1_Display_Name" 
     ows_Editor="6;#User2_Display_Name" ows_owshiddenversion="4" 
     ows_Attachments="0" ows__ModerationStatus="0" 
     ows_LinkTitleNoMenu="Title" 
     ows_LinkTitle="Title" ows_SelectTitle="6" 
     ows_Order="600.000000000000" 
     ows_GUID="{2E8D2505-98FD-4E3E-BFDA-0C3DEBE483F7}" 
     ows_DateColumn="2003-06-23 00:00:00" 
     ows_NumberColumn="9001.00000000000000" 
     xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema" />
  </Result>

</Results>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SPServices CRUD Operations you could do like bellow code to check your operation completed successfully or not
if you get the error code value: 0x0000000 it means your operation completed successfully without error.

```
  $().SPServices({
        operation: "UpdateListItems",
        batchCmd: "New",
        listName: "YourListName",
        valuepairs: [["PersonnelID",PersonalId],["ETA",SetNullDates(ETA)]],
        completefunc: function (xData, Status) {

                        var $xml= $(xData.responseText);
                        var ErrorVal = $xml.find("ErrorCode").text();
                        if(ErrorVal=="0x00000000")
                        {
                            alert("Operation Success");
                            //-----Display a message that operation is success
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            alert("Un Expected Error Occurred, Please contact SharePoint Admins");
                        }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to iterate through the results looking for any errors, then use something like this:

```
var xml = $($.parseXML( yourXMLstring ));
var errors = xml.find("ErrorCode");
for (var i=0; i<errors.length; i++)
{
  alert( "Error for '" + errors[i].parentNode.getAttribute("ID") + 
         "' = " + errors[i].textContent );
}
```